# Which site would be suitable for this question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on behavior of myself in certain situations. I want suggestions from SE users.

To be more specific, my question is:

> When I get involve in Hard conversation or When I get involved in feud or during oral fights, My voice becomes faint, I loose darkness in my voice, My hands and legs shake. Why does this happens? Can it be overcome?
>
> Where it happens : Actually everywhere. Let it be work, let it be employee under me or let it be my domestic helper or even with friends and relatives.

Comment: In personal or professional life?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, i.e. posting your actual question? Right now, it's a bit vague and there are probably many sites which *could* be the right match.

Comment: Go watch the beginning of Full Metal Jacket.  A hundred times.  Practice your war face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a site related to the setting of the occasion, like [the Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) if it happens at work, or [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) if it happens in a scholar environment.

Another site I was thinking of is this proposal: [Interpersonal Skills](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills), which seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

> Proposed Q&A site for the life skills we use every day to communicate and interact with other people.

Comment: Slight correction: If the question is "This thing happens to me, how can I alleviate any negative effect it might have in my interactions in a specific academic context"  then it might be on topic on Academia (if the academic context is graduate school or higher). But if it's "Why does my body do this, and how can I make it not happen", as stated in the question, then it's probably out of scope even if it happens to occur in an academic setting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about situations at work, conversations with your boss?
In this case, you could try the [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Actually everywhere. Let it be work, let it be employee under me or let it be my domestic helper or even with friends and relatives.

Comment: @user39390, if it is in general situations, you should follow Patrick Hofman's advice, and go to [Interpersonal Skills](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills) which is still in Area 51.